# Is it possible to get encryption algoritm by compearing plain test and encypted text?

Tags: passwords, computer-science

I don't know if it is possible.
suppose I have a plain text **123**.after encypting the text it becomes **234**.
now i have both plain text and encypted text.
Can i get the encyption algoritm from these?

Comment: If you are lucky it's a Caesar encryption with "length" = 1, means each character gets shifted by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to mean by "get" and "algorithm". Because if you want to know in your mind what the algorithm is - then yes, after some analysis you could get that (mostly for simpler algorithms). Also you could understand the algorithm even after some paper+pencil work if such would be needed. Third option is to get algorithm in form of computer language - this depends on algorithm complexity and rules = mode of action. For some algorithms you could be able to write a computer language code to encrypt/decrypt, but for some - not (it's rare, many things can be coded).

Mostly if you can understand the given algorithm (you know how to encrypt or decrypt) then you can write code for one/both of these processes.